# fs.write confusion why only 5 params are needed?

Tags: node.js

In the doc, it says: 
fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)
however if I use 
fs.write(fd, buffer, null, null, null, function(){})
it doesn't work as it supposed to, only 
fs.write(fd, buffer, null, null, function(){}) will do
what's the difference? why only 5 params are needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

optional parameters should not be provided at all, so do'nt write nulls at all.
fs.write(fd, buffer, function() {})

Comment: you are right, because per documentation, they are not optional :) http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback and it looks like you can only put null for position and rest must be provided. by the way http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode this one is an example of a function with optional params that you can ignore.